# Django - Check Other Objects Prior to Save

Tags: python, django

I want to override the built-in django `.save()` method to perform a check against all other objects in the database.

```
For example:

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class Admin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class SecurityGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    users = models.ManytoManyField(User)
    admins = models.ManytoManyField(Admin)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # check admins don't exist in any other SecurityGroup prior to save

        super(SecurityGroup, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) example is pretty simple, and doesn't describe this type of pre-save check.

I have tried adding in lines to `.save()` such as:

```
`self.objects.filter(admins__name=self.admins.name).count()`
```

to call the other SecurityGroup objects but I receive the error:

```
`Manager is not accessible via SecurityGroup instance`
```

Is it possible to achieve this save functionality internal to the SecurityGroup Model, or do I need to create a `form` and use `SecurityGroup.save(commit=False)` for this type of pre-save check?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you have error in call `super` change it to `SecurityGroup` and if you whant to check before save new instance you can check if `self.pk` exists

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the error.  Do you have a more complete answer to provide?

Comment: please, read full comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to override the Model's `form` in `admin.py`.  This enabled a simple check whether admins already existed in a `SecurityGroup` or not.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import ModelForm

from security.models import SecurityGroup


class SecurityGroupAdminForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SecurityGroup
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):    
        # CHECK 1
        if admins:
            admins = self.cleaned_data['admins']

        for a in admins:
            existing_group = SecurityGroup.objects.filter(users__username=a.username)

            if existing_group:
                raise Exception("message")



        return self.cleaned_data
```

Then, within the same `admin.py` file, indicate the custom form as part of the admin registration for the model of interest (in this case, `SecurityGroup`):

```
class UserSecurityGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # class Meta:
    model = UserSecurityGroup
    form = UserSecurityGroupAdminForm

admin.site.register(UserSecurityGroup, UserSecurityGroupAdmin)
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is caused by accessing the Manager of a model through a model instance. You should have used

```
self.model_class().objects
```

Comment: In looking into this, one has to access an instance's model class via the django `ContentType` class (and not through a `Model` class instance): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType.model_class.  Using the method you described returned an AttributeError.